# Why does laravel resize my website on mobile?

Tags: php, css, laravel, tailwind-css

I'm currently building my first site in laravel but i ran into an issue. When i inspect or view the site on mobile everything is much smaller than it should be. I inspected the font size and it says everything should be correct however everything is way smaller on the whole website than it should be.

Is there a hidden setting or something that i need to switch off? I Use tailwind for my css on all websites but this never happens on my wordpress sites.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's not laravel, it's your HTML that doesn't set the scale for mobile.
You need to set the device width and initial scale for the website to show at the same scale as browser

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag